# How to re-run the app after crash the server in strapi?

Tags: node.js, strapi

I'm new to use `strapi` and I got error while add data.

```
Error: SQLITE_ERROR: Cannot add a NOT NULL column with default value NULL
```

And after that my app has gone a crash. Now I re-run the command.

```
strapi start
```

But still I got the same error. So how could I start the app again?

Comment: then ALTER your table to allow NULL values, or fix your insert code/model whatnot that it does not pass in null but what the column expects. you may need to download the db and edit it locally, woos of sqlite

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Yes, I update the data in db and it works for me. Please add your answer so I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ Lawrence Cherone suggested, I have ALTER my table to allow NULL values. And it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1) You really shouldn't be using SQLite in production as it was never added for that purpose.

2) Based on the error it sounds like you are using develop mode in production (Content-Type builder) which also is not recommended.

You should look at using something like PM2 for autorestarts and process management

Comment: I just create a project and it automatically used sqllite.